# How to sum column based on another column's data

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I have an sql table with columns Part Number, Quantity, Reason, and Area. I want to get the sums of quantity based on one reason from each area. So for example, I want to know the total numbers of parts with reason code A from each distinct area.

```
SELECT Distinct sum(quantity), Area Where [Reason Code] LIKE 'A%' Order By Area.
```

Comment: Syntax does not look like `mysql` but `sqlserver`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty ahh it is sql server, sorry for the tag, i have updated the question.

Comment: and in both cases, you're probably missing a `group by`. in fact if you just change `order` to `group`, and get rid of the distinct, you should get what you want

Comment: @pala_ It was a group by statement, I dont know why I was using Order By. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE---------------------

I needed to switch my order by to a group by clause

```
SELECT Distinct sum(quantity), Area Where [Reason Code] LIKE 'A%' Group By Area.
```